# Object-Oriented Programming Accessing functions within a class without parameters(python)

Tags: python, class, oop, parameters, abstract-class

EDIT: I hope this is more clear on my concerns. **I understood that this had to much information for the question that i was seeking an answer to. Also, expressMeal and megaMeal are on two different files. The user must enter a 1 or 2, and im suppose to call the instance variables with that.
My questions are in bold, the rest is bit of background on this program**

First off, i would like to apologize if this is confusing or if I'm not making myself clear. This is my first time writing on stackoverflow.com.

I have to write a python program about A fast food restaurant. It has two types of meals for customers to choose. An express meal includes meat and side item. A mega meal includes meat, side item, drink and dessert. In the both files The **init** method is only suppose to have the self parameter. Also i have to define a chooseMeat method to choose the meat, a chooseSide method to choose the side item, and a displayOrder method to display items ordered. this is what i have done so far.

```
>class ExpressMeal:
>>   def __init__(self):
>>>      self._meat = ' '
         self._side = ' '
     def chooseMeat(self):       
         return self._meat
     def chooseSide(self):
         return self._side
     def displayOrder(self):
```

in both files The **init** method has only the self parameter. I have to use this constructor to initialize the instance variables to empty strings. I have to call the ExpressMeal constructor.**Also, im suppose to call the
displayOrder method of the ExpressMeal class to this file. How can i do that?** I apologize in advance, as I have not been able to work on this too much, because I don't understand how to make the expressMeal.py work.

```
from expressMeal import ExpressMeal
class MegaMeal(ExpressMeal):
    def __init__(self):
         base = super()
         self._drink = ' '
         self._dessert = ' '
```

I have to import megaMeal.py to the main module file and ask the user to choose either express meal or mega meal. **Also  i have to create the appropriate object and call its methods to input and display items chosen by the customer. How can i achieve this**? ***I'm stuck. I don't understand how im suppose to call the variables (for expressMeal just meat, and side, but for megaMeal i have to call meat, side, drink, and dessert) to the main module, if __init__ is only suppose to have the self parameter and nothing else. Is this possible?*** 
The following shows a sample run on this program

> `Enter 1 for express meal 
>   Enter 2 for mega meal: 1 
>   You chose express meal 
>   Enter 1 for chicken sandwich Enter 2 for cheese burger: 2 
>   Enter 1 for fries Enter 2 for chips: 1 
>   Items ordered: cheese burger fries`

The program is suppose to execute like this when finished
I'm not asking for it to be done for me in its entirety. But if i could get help on how to make it work with examples. Any help is hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I imagine that `chooseMeat` and `chooseSide` are supposed to set the meat and side value in the class, not return the value

Comment: Just some advice on your question: you have a lot of unrelated details that make it hard to identify what's important and what isn't. I've had to read the entire thing 3 times before I understood that only the last paragraph had the important information for what you're asking.

Comment: I haven't read all your question, but this "__init__ is only suppose to have the self parameter and nothing else." Is not correct! You can call init with as many parameters as you like, as long as the first is self.

Comment: I apologize for that, i tried to be as clear as possible but ended up being worst. @Ni The "init is only suppose to have the self parameter" per the instructions of this program.

Answer (score 1):

In Python the "official" normal way is (in Python 3)

```
class MegaMeal(ExpressMeal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._drink = ' '
        self._dessert = ' '
```

for a way that works in both Python 3 and 2 and that IMO requires less "magic" to be understood replace `super` call with

```
ExpressMeal.__init__(self)
```

In my opinion `super` with Python 2 is way too confusing to be understood (or even just memorized) at your level, so just leave that alone. I know happy productive Python programmers that don't even know that `super` exists.